Error Creating CSV Data File From A JSON data
I am using Pandas and other libraries to create a timetable csv data file for a game. I am encountering error while running it. Please provide any suggestions on correcting my code.
class Read_Create_TimeTable_File:

    def __init__(self, file_path=None):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.existing_timetable_data = None
        if file_path is not None:
            self.load_timetable_data(file_path)

    def set_file_path(self, file_path):
        if not file_path.endswith(".timetable_or"):
            file_path += ".timetable_or"
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.load_timetable_data(file_path)

    def load_timetable_data(self, file_path):
        try:
            self.existing_timetable_data= pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=";", encoding="utf-16le")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.timetable_data = None

    def load_timetable_data_from_json(self, json_file_path):
        try:
            with open(json_file_path, "r") as f:
                data_dict = json.load(f)
            data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
            data = data.transpose()
            data.index.name = "Station"
            self.timetable_data = data  # Ensure this attribute is set correctly
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.timetable_data = None

    def create_timetable_file(self, file_path, data=None):

        if data is None:
            if hasattr(self, 'timetable_data'):
                data = self.timetable_data
            else:
                raise ValueError("Data must be provided.")

        if file_path is not None:
            self.file_path = file_path 
        if self.file_path is None:
            raise ValueError("File path must be provided.")
        if data is None:
            raise ValueError("Data must be provided.") 

        if not file_path.endswith(".timetable_or"):
            file_path += ".timetable_or"

        data.insert(0, '#comment', '')
        data.insert(0, '', '')

        data = data.reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "Station"})   

        mandatory_rows = [
            ["#comment", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            ["#path /binary", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            ["#consist", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            ["#start", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            ["#speedkph", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            ["#comment", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            ["#note", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            ["#dispose", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            [""] * len(data.columns),
        ]

        mandatory_rows_df = pd.DataFrame(mandatory_rows, columns=data.columns) 

        for col in data.columns[3:]:
            for row in ["#comment", "#path /binary", "#consist"]:
                row_index = mandatory_rows_df[mandatory_rows_df["Station"] == row].index[0]
                mandatory_rows_df.loc[row_index, col] = col 

        first_comment_index = mandatory_rows_df[mandatory_rows_df["Station"] == "#comment"].index[0]
        mandatory_rows_df.loc[first_comment_index, "#comment"] = file_path.replace(".timetable_or","")

        for mandatory_row in ["#start", "#speedkph", "#dispose"]:
            if mandatory_row in data["Station"].values:
                row_data = data[data["Station"] == mandatory_row].iloc[0]
                row_index = mandatory_rows_df[mandatory_rows_df["Station"] == mandatory_row].index[0]
                for col in data.columns[3:]:
                    mandatory_rows_df.loc[row_index, col] = row_data[col]
                data = data[data["Station"] != mandatory_row]

        final_data = pd.concat([mandatory_rows_df, data], ignore_index=True)

        # Save to CSV with UTF-16LE encoding
        final_data.to_csv(file_path, sep=";", index=False, encoding="utf-16le")
        print(f"Timetable file created at {file_path}") ``` 






Json File Looks like this:
{
  "20980/Jaipur - Udaipur City Vande Bharat Express": {
    "#start": "19:30",
    "#speedkph": "110",
    "#dispose": "",
    "Chittaurgarh Junction/COR": "19:45-19:55",
    "Mavli Jn/MVJ": "20:52-20:54",
    "Udaipur City/UDZ": "22:08"
  },
  "09601/Udaipur City - Chittaurgarh Passenger Special (UnReserved)": {
    "#start": "19:25",
    "#speedkph": "110",
    "#dispose": "",
    "Chittaurgarh Junction/COR": "22:15",
    "Ghosunda/GSD": "21:41-21:42",
    "Netawal/NTWL": "21:23-21:24",
    "Pandoli/PMO": "21:14-21:15",
    "Kapasan/KIN": "21:04-21:05",
    "Bhupalsagar/BSJ": "20:53-20:54",
    "Fatehnagar/FAN": "20:41-20:42",
    "Mavli Jn/MVJ": "20:25-20:30",
    "Bhimal/BIML": "20:14-20:15",
    "Khemli/KLH": "20:02-20:03",
    "Debari/DRB": "19:50-19:51",
    "Ranapratapnagar/RPZ": "19:36-19:38",
    "Udaipur City/UDZ": "19:30"
  }
}

The name of the train: for eg (20980/Jaipur - Udaipur City Vande Bharat Express) should be added as a new column and the values in it should be added as the respective rows and the values to the respective intersecting cells.
Error I am facing: ValueError: Data must be provided.
what changes be required for the same?

Here is your corrected code. You did mistakes in the loading part of the json file:
import pandas as pd
import json

class Read_Create_TimeTable_File:

    def __init__(self, file_path=None):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.existing_timetable_data = None
        self.timetable_data = None
        if file_path is not None:
            self.load_timetable_data(file_path)

    def set_file_path(self, file_path):
        if not file_path.endswith(".timetable_or"):
            file_path += ".timetable_or"
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.load_timetable_data(file_path)

    def load_timetable_data(self, file_path):
        try:
            self.existing_timetable_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=";", encoding="utf-16le")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.existing_timetable_data = None

    def load_timetable_data_from_json(self, json_file_path):
        try:
            with open(json_file_path, "r") as f:
                data_dict = json.load(f)
            data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict).transpose()
            data.index.name = "Train"
            self.timetable_data = data.reset_index() 
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.timetable_data = None

    def create_timetable_file(self, file_path=None, data=None):
        if data is None:
            if self.timetable_data is not None:
                data = self.timetable_data
            else:
                raise ValueError("Data must be provided.")

        if file_path is not None:
            self.file_path = file_path 
        if self.file_path is None:
            raise ValueError("File path must be provided.")

        if not file_path.endswith(".timetable_or"):
            file_path += ".timetable_or"

        data.insert(0, '#comment', '')
        data.insert(0, '', '')

        data = data.rename_axis("Station").reset_index()

        mandatory_rows = [
            ["#comment", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            ["#path /binary", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            ["#consist", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            ["#start", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            ["#speedkph", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            ["#comment", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            ["#note", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            ["#dispose", "", "", ""] + [""] * (len(data.columns) - 4),
            [""] * len(data.columns),
        ]

        mandatory_rows_df = pd.DataFrame(mandatory_rows, columns=data.columns)

        for col in data.columns[3:]:
            for row in ["#comment", "#path /binary", "#consist"]:
                row_index = mandatory_rows_df[mandatory_rows_df["Station"] == row].index[0]
                mandatory_rows_df.loc[row_index, col] = col

        first_comment_index = mandatory_rows_df[mandatory_rows_df["Station"] == "#comment"].index[0]
        mandatory_rows_df.loc[first_comment_index, "#comment"] = file_path.replace(".timetable_or", "")

        for mandatory_row in ["#start", "#speedkph", "#dispose"]:
            if mandatory_row in data["Station"].values:
                row_data = data[data["Station"] == mandatory_row].iloc[0]
                row_index = mandatory_rows_df[mandatory_rows_df["Station"] == mandatory_row].index[0]
                for col in data.columns[3:]:
                    mandatory_rows_df.loc[row_index, col] = row_data[col]
                data = data[data["Station"] != mandatory_row]

        final_data = pd.concat([mandatory_rows_df, data], ignore_index=True)

        final_data.to_csv(self.file_path, sep=";", index=False, encoding="utf-16le")
        print(f"Timetable file created at {self.file_path}")

filepath = r"C:\Users\serge.degossondevare\Documents\Python Scripts\data-investigation\jsondata.json"
file_creator = Read_Create_TimeTable_File()
file_creator.load_timetable_data_from_json("jsondata.json")
file_creator.create_timetable_file("output.timetable_or")


Here I use jsondata.json as the file name.
It returns a csv file:
Station;;#comment;Train;#start;#speedkph;#dispose;Chittaurgarh Junction/COR;Mavli Jn/MVJ;Udaipur City/UDZ;Ghosunda/GSD;Netawal/NTWL;Pandoli/PMO;Kapasan/KIN;Bhupalsagar/BSJ;Fatehnagar/FAN;Bhimal/BIML;Khemli/KLH;Debari/DRB;Ranapratapnagar/RPZ
#comment;;output;Train;#start;#speedkph;#dispose;Chittaurgarh Junction/COR;Mavli Jn/MVJ;Udaipur City/UDZ;Ghosunda/GSD;Netawal/NTWL;Pandoli/PMO;Kapasan/KIN;Bhupalsagar/BSJ;Fatehnagar/FAN;Bhimal/BIML;Khemli/KLH;Debari/DRB;Ranapratapnagar/RPZ
#path /binary;;;Train;#start;#speedkph;#dispose;Chittaurgarh Junction/COR;Mavli Jn/MVJ;Udaipur City/UDZ;Ghosunda/GSD;Netawal/NTWL;Pandoli/PMO;Kapasan/KIN;Bhupalsagar/BSJ;Fatehnagar/FAN;Bhimal/BIML;Khemli/KLH;Debari/DRB;Ranapratapnagar/RPZ
#consist;;;Train;#start;#speedkph;#dispose;Chittaurgarh Junction/COR;Mavli Jn/MVJ;Udaipur City/UDZ;Ghosunda/GSD;Netawal/NTWL;Pandoli/PMO;Kapasan/KIN;Bhupalsagar/BSJ;Fatehnagar/FAN;Bhimal/BIML;Khemli/KLH;Debari/DRB;Ranapratapnagar/RPZ
#start;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
#speedkph;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
#comment;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
#note;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
#dispose;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
0;;;20980/Jaipur - Udaipur City Vande Bharat Express;19:30;110;;19:45-19:55;20:52-20:54;22:08;;;;;;;;;;
1;;;09601/Udaipur City - Chittaurgarh Passenger Special (UnReserved);19:25;110;;22:15;20:25-20:30;19:30;21:41-21:42;21:23-21:24;21:14-21:15;21:04-21:05;20:53-20:54;20:41-20:42;20:14-20:15;20:02-20:03;19:50-19:51;19:36-19:38


